# Paypal discount code with buy now button

Tags: button, paypal, e-commerce, discount

I've created a paypal buy now button and integrated it successfully. When testing I notice that once I reach the paypal site there's an option to redeem a "voucher, reward or other discount".

How do I create the voucher/discount codes?

The instructions I've seen so far seem to relate to handling the coupon codes on your own website i.e. you have to allow users to enter the code on your site. I'm looking for a solution where my customers can redeem a coupon code on the paypal website using the option I mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant create vouchers. Only paypal or ebay users can create those.
You're gonna have to create a script that calculates the discounts on your website before sending the total amount to paypal checkout. 
Check a script i posted on my profile for more info.

Comment: This is what I did in the end

Answer (score 0):

If you are using V2 of the PayPal API, add it as part of the breakdown. 
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-amount_breakdown